# jQuery .then() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, internet-explorer-11

I am using jQuery (v3.3.1-min) promises to chain some function calls as they are dependent on each other. 
For most of the part the sequencing works fine, but for for some nested calls it does not wait for the previous function to finish and jumps to the next line of code. It does return to it some time later, but the values could not be used at that moment as the HTML table has already been prepared by then.

I will try to explain with some code samples here.

Initializing code [line# 360/61/62]:

```
GetUpstreamTrace(classID, selectedFeatOID, minSeqNo, maxSeqNo).then(function () {//line#360
    GetConnectedTrace().then(function () { //line#361
       PopulateTraceTable(); //line#362
    });
});
```

Within *GetUpstreamTrace()*, I call several other methods, some of which are XHRs while rest are usual methods. The XHRs seem to honor the promise every time, as it gets *resolved* within *onreadystatechange* block.

Weird behaving code [line#: 527-596]:

```
$.each(queryResultJson.features, function (indx, queryFeat) {//line#527
        //fetch values
        console.log("  Inside $.each() [line# 499], index=" + indx);
        connectorClassId = parseInt(queryFeat.attributes["CONNECTOR_CLASSID"]);
        connectorObjectId = parseInt(queryFeat.attributes["CONNECTOR_OBJECTID"]);
        toObjId = parseInt(queryFeat.attributes["TO_OBJECTID"]);
        toClsId = parseInt(queryFeat.attributes["TO_CLASSID"]);
        fromObjId = parseInt(queryFeat.attributes["FROM_OBJECTID"]);
        fromClsId = parseInt(queryFeat.attributes["FROM_CLASSID"]);
        toFirstUnit = parseInt(queryFeat.attributes["TO_FIRSTUNIT"]);
        fromFirstUnit = parseInt(queryFeat.attributes["FROM_FIRSTUNIT"]);
        numberOfUnits = parseInt(queryFeat.attributes["NUMBER_OF_UNITS"]);

        if ((minSeqNo >= toFirstUnit && minSeqNo < (toFirstUnit + numberOfUnits)) || (toFirstUnit >= minSeqNo && toFirstUnit < (minSeqNo + maxSeqNo))) {
            if (numberOfUnits >= maxSeqNo) {
                if ((minSeqNo + maxSeqNo) > (toFirstUnit + numberOfUnits))
                    numberOfUnits = (toFirstUnit + numberOfUnits) - minSeqNo;
                else
                    numberOfUnits = maxSeqNo;

                fromFirstUnit = (minSeqNo - toFirstUnit) + fromFirstUnit;
                toFirstUnit = minSeqNo;
            }
            else {
                if (minSeqNo > toFirstUnit) {
                    numberOfUnits = (toFirstUnit + numberOfUnits) - minSeqNo;
                    fromFirstUnit = (minSeqNo - toFirstUnit) + fromFirstUnit;
                    toFirstUnit = minSeqNo;
                }
            }
            //line# 558
            GetConnectedInfo(selectedFeatOID, classID, minSeqNo, maxSeqNo, toObjId, toClsId, toFirstUnit, numberOfUnits, fromObjId, fromClsId, fromFirstUnit).then(function (connectedInfoResult) {
                connectionInfo += connectedInfoResult;
                //console.log("  After GetConnectedInfo [line# 530]...");
                //console.log("  connectionInfo [line# 492]: " + connectedInfoResult);
                objTable += '{' +
                                '"OBJECTID" : "' + fromObjId + '", ' +
                                '"OBJ_CLASSID" : "' + fromClsId + '", ' +
                                '"FROM_FIRSTUNIT" : "' + toFirstUnit + '", ' +
                                '"TO_FIRSTUNIT" : "' + fromFirstUnit + '", ' +
                                '"NO_OF_UNIT" : "' + numberOfUnits + '"' +
                            '},';
                //console.log("  objTable [line# 533]: " + objTable);
                totalUnitCount += numberOfUnits;
            });

            //});
        }
    });

    //line# 578
    var objTableJson = '', tmpObjTable = '';
    if (objTable.length > 0) {
        tmpObjTable = objTable;
        tmpObjTable = tmpObjTable.slice(0, tmpObjTable.lastIndexOf(','));
        tmpObjTable = '[' + tmpObjTable + ']';

        objTableJson = JSON.parse(tmpObjTable);
    }
    //console.log("  tmpObjTable [line# 548]: " + tmpObjTable);
    if (objTableJson.length == 0) {
        if (checkConnected == true) {
            GetConnectedInfo(selectedFeatOID, classID, minSeqNo, maxSeqNo, selectedFeatOID, classID, minSeqNo, maxSeqNo, 0, 0, 0).then(function (connectedInfoResult) {
                connectionInfo += connectedInfoResult;//line#: 590
                totalUnitCount = numberOfUnits;
                console.log("  After GetConnectedInfo [line# 557]...");
                //console.log("  connectionInfo [line# 492]: " + connectedInfoResult);
            });
        }
    }
```

The program flow I am getting is like this:
Line 360 >> 527 >> 558 >> 361 >> 362 >> 578 >> 590...

I am not able to understand why is it not waiting for *GetConnectedInfo* to finish and jumping out of line.

Any pointers???

Thanks in advance!

UJ

**Update**
So to explain the issue I am facing, I created this simple code using $.each. The same things happens here as well...you will notice that $.each finishes first and then the nested .then. 
My understanding was that $.each will not move to next iteration until .then() completes, but it does not! Still bewildered, not sure if I am missing something very basic.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function doSomething(){
            console.log("Inside doSomething()...");

            var arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

            $.each(arr,function(indx,item){
                console.log(" Inside $.each - index/item: "+indx+"/"+item);

                $.when(doSomethingElse(item)).done(function(response){
                console.log("  doSomethingElse response..."+response);  [![Working demo][1]][1] 
                });                 
            });

            console.log("Back inside doSomething()!");
        }

        function doSomethingElse(intgr){
            var def=$.Deferred();

            def.resolve("  doSomethingElse"+intgr);

            return def.promise();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="doSomething()">
    <h2>jQuery Promise Test. Check console messages for details.</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

If you need all of the `GetConnectedInfo()` requests to complete in the `each` loop before moving on then you would create an array of those promises and can use `Promise.all()` (or `$.when()`) to run after they all have resolved

Instead of using `each` try

```
var feature_promises = queryResultJson.features.map(function(queryFeat, indx) {
  console.log("  Inside $.each() [line# 499], index=" + indx);

  //......

  //line# 558  RETURN THE PROMISE TO MAPPED ARRAY
  return GetConnectedInfo( /* args */ ).then(function(connectedInfoResult) {
    //......

   // return something
  })
});

Promise.all(feature_promises).then(function(results){
    //line# 578
    var objTableJson = '', tmpObjTable = '';
    if (objTable.length > 0) {
       //......

)}
```

---

You should never ever create JSON manually. It is error prone and more work than directly using objects. Instead of adding strings to `objectTable` it should be array that you push actual objects into

Comment: I tried this approach, but it still behaves in the same manner as before. "return GetConnectedInfo" within features_promises is called again after the flow has moved out of the block. Btw, any reason for recommending against $.each? To me $.each and $.map both look same in behavior.

Comment: I've updated my question to include a demo of the issue...please have a look.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. The `each` loop does not wait for `then()` to complete because it is **asynchronous**

Comment: No, $.each is not asynchronous!
That's why I am confused why it is moving over the .then block, where it should wait for it to finish. Whats the point of using .then if the code moves past it?

Comment: Not the `each` itself...the promise inside the each is asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I finally got it working and this is how (plus, why it behaved the way it did).

Going through the jQuery 3.0 upgrade notes, I came across the following:
**[Breaking change and Feature: jQuery.Deferred is now Promises/A+ compatible](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-and-feature-jquery-deferred-is-now-promises-a-compatible)**

> Another behavior change required for Promises/A+ compliance is that
>   Deferred .then() callbacks are always called asynchronously.
>   Previously, if a .then() callback was added to a Deferred that was
>   already resolved or rejected, the callback would run immediately and
>   synchronously.

Because I am consuming the same library in my development as well as demo code posted here, the behavior I was seeing was how it should actually be (and confusing me!).

The recommendation is to use *$.when()* and *.done()* to get the old style synchronous behavior.

> Deferred methods such as .done(), .fail(), and .pipe() retain their
>   old behavior and so are not Promises/A+ compliant. If you require
>   synchronous resolution, do not want exceptions converted to rejection
>   values or rejection callback returns converted to fulfillment values,
>   or want thrown errors to bubble out of the function where they occur,
>   you can use these methods instead of .then() and .catch().

Posting the updated code for the demo here as well.

UJ

[image]